# Rails 4: Sass raises SyntaxError when precompiling assets on server but not on development computer

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, syntax-error

Here is the error I get when running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` on the server:

`Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...5,255,255,0.9);": expected "}", was "!important"
(in /var/www/deploy/project/releases/20141230211654/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):15782`

It also takes an unreasonably long time to precompile the assets on the server(Ubuntu).

On the other hand, Sass makes no complaints when I run the same rake task on my computer(Debian) and the precompilation takes a mere few seconds.

Why is this?  I understand that there's a syntax error in the CSS, but why would my own instance of this Rails project not care about bad CSS syntax while the server does?

Comment: did you checked the line with the problem? Maybe you put `important` after `;`.. `background: (255,255,255,0.9); !important`. Also on the server you are in production. When you test on your local machine do you compile assets for production or development? Make sure you export RAILS_ENV=production before compilation or use: `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`. Weird thing.. I'm 100% sure you have an error in sass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference was that I was not setting the environment on my machine to production.

So I should have been running:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

I speculate that, in development, Rails merely concatenates unminified javascripts and css whereas the production environment does actual compilation using uglifier & sass, thus every part of the css gets parsed and errors get raised.